# Query for data in Postgresql with forward slash in jsonb field

Tags: postgresql

I have a transactions table which has a jsonb field with some additional info. I am storing some invoice numbers in jsonb which contain `/` in them. While trying to query it I am facing an error. How to query for json containing this invoice number with forward slash?

---

---

```
SELECT * 
FROM "transactions" 
WHERE transactions"."other_data" -> 'invoice_number'='ABC1/211/000359';
```

I am getting below error

```
LINE 1: ...transactions where other_data -> 'invoice_number'='ABC1/211...

                                                             ^

DETAIL:  Token "ABC1" is invalid.

CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: ABC1...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html), the operator `->` returns a `json` value, but you are trying to compare it to a string (varchar) value. So Postgres tries to convert the right hand side to a `json` value.

You need to extract the value as a string using the `->>` operator

```
WHERE transactions"."other_data" ->> 'invoice_number' = 'ABC1/211/000359';
```